# Custom Center UIButton does not appear when using generated center point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitabbar

I am trying to make a center UIButton in the middle of a UITabBar. My first approach to doing this was figuring out the exact center of UITabBar by trial and error

```
UIButton *cameraButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"show-sheet"];
cameraButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.tabBar.frame.size.width - image.size.width - 187, -image.size.height + 44, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[cameraButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cameraButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.tabBar addSubview:cameraButton];
```

As you can see I used hard coded values for x and y, which doesn't work on different screen sizes, this solution works well for iPhone 6+ screen size. I am trying to figure coordinates that would work on all screen sizes. After some googling I found that the desired behavior is achieved by doing something like this

```
UIButton *cameraButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"show-sheet"];
cameraButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width , image.size.height);
[cameraButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cameraButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
CGFloat heightDifference = cameraButton.frame.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
if (heightDifference < 0) {
    NSLog(@"heightDifference");
    cameraButton.center = self.tabBar.center;
} else {
    NSLog(@"not heightDifference");
    CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
    center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
    cameraButton.center = center;
}
[self.tabBar addSubview:cameraButton];
```

with this approach the button is hidden and I can't see it anywhere on the screen or the tab bar. I did some debugging and found the the center of the button is exactly the same as the center of the tab bar but it's not being shown. Any ideas as to what is going on?

edit: I inspected a view hierarchy and found the button in the center but down by about 40 pts.

Comment: Why are you adding the button to the tab bar, and not using `UITabBarItem`?

Comment: I because I want to perform an action when the user taps not switch to a different viewcontroller

Comment: OK. Did you inspect a view hierarchy? Instructions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: I did inspect it and when I clicked on "show clipped content" I found the uibutton in the center indeed but below the window by about 40pts. how to go about fixing this?

Comment: you can use: **- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController**

Comment: @Karim I tried this method and it doesn't even get fired. My UITabBarViewController is conforming to tabbar and tabbarcontroller protocols

Comment: Please paste that part of code (delegate methods, and where you are registering to the delegate). I think @Karim solution is better than yours. It's not good solution to add subviews to the UITabBar.